# React Native - Setting return value of function to a component's property not working

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, react-native

I am using the react native switch component and want to change the state of a switch (on/off) programmatically when state changes for another switch. Below is the code I have:

```
update = (key: string, val: boolean) => {
    if(key == 'togglekey') {
        this.state.somekey = !val;
    }
};

<Switch onValueChange={(v) => this.update('somekey', v)} value={this.state.somekey} />

<Switch onValueChange={(v) => this.update('togglekey', v)} value={this.state.togglekey} />
```

When I click on the togglekey switch, I am expecting the somekey switch to toggle on or off, but it is not working. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mutate state directly. You must use `setState` instead, only then will React acknowledge the state update.

```
update = (key: string, val: boolean) => {
    if(key == 'togglekey') {
        this.setState({somekey: !val});
    }
};
```